# Change the color of an ExpandableListView item 

Tags: android, expandablelistview, simplecursoradapter

... by using a cursor to select individual (infinite) rows from three different columns in a sql db.*The first column contains the id. The second column contains the net weight and the third column contains the actual weight.* There are more columns in the db, but the preceding columns are the only relevant ones.

Next I need to take the two numbers and do some simple arithmetic... (Easy, not a problem) then....

If the row contains an actual weight that is less than 15 percent of the net weight, turn this item's expandableListView background red. If not stay green or purple or pink or whatever!

### HERE ARE MY SPECS:

**simpleCursorTreeAdapter** that is linked to a **sql database** and **ExpandableListView.**

### HERE IS WHAT I HAVE FOUND:

I have read several different tutorials, androiddocs, q&a's and they all point to a getGroupView(). The problem with all the tutorials is this: the adapter is extended from **BaseExpandableListAdapter**. Unfortunately, I have been down that road, a few times. I am working with a sql lite database.

However, I noticed that *SimpleCursorTreeAdapter extends BaseExpandableAdapter*. So, there should be a way to make this work.

### THE PROBLEM:

I need to find a way to cycle through individual positions using getGroupView(). Unlike the [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645104/android-expandablelistview/5645596#5645596) that is peppered all over the net, my data is coming from a db and I am not using check boxes.

I can use groupView to successfully turn all of the items green or red, but there is no way to do what I need with one return statement.!

Any thoughts where I should look? I want to hold off on posting the code til I get some interest.

Answer (score 0):

go here: [Android: Access TextView inside Child of ExpandableListViewActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948285/android-access-textview-inside-child-of-expandablelistviewactivity) and set the color of the views as they are fetched from the adapter based on the data in your sql database.

Then call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter to force the views to be fetched again, which will show their new colors if the sql db has changed.

Answer (score 0):

this is efficient way to set group indicator

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
android:state_empty="true" >
<layer-list>
    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="20dp"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_down">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

```
<item
android:state_expanded="false" >
<layer-list>
    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="20dp"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_up">
    </item>
</layer-list>
</item>
```